# I have two classes with same name and same package structure in different jars. Is it possbile to choose a class from jar specifically?

Tags: java, overloading

As mentioned I I have two classes with same name and same package structure in different jars.
Lets say
in **jar1** my class is **a.b.c.ClassName** and
in **jar2** my class is **a.b.c.ClassName**.
I have different constructors for the classes to differentiate.

My question is, Is it possible to create object based on constructor.
Example,

```
if(condition){
a.b.c.ClassName obj = new a.b.c.ClassName(Param);
}
else{
a.b.c.ClassName obj = new a.b.c.ClassName(Param, AnotherParam);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have worked on a few projects over the years which have identical class package/names in different jars and it has caused nothing but trouble. I consider it a bug that dual classes exist, even though java has its rules about which it will find first, I don't know the history of your project but I would recommended solving this issue if possible. rant over :)

Comment: first of all, how did you compile this?

Comment: You have a major design error. Fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, Is it possible to create object based on constructor.

I take you to be asking whether Java will choose from which jar to load the class based on which version of the class has a constructor matching the given signature.  No, it will not.  Java will look for the designated class in the directories and jars in the classpath, in order, and will use the first one it finds.

It is conceivable that you could write a custom ClassLoader that would assist you in choosing which version of the class to load based on the signatures of available constructors, but such capabilities would not trigger automatically, as you seem to want.  Java loads the class before it considers which constructors are available in it.  You would need to load the class manually, and probably to instantiate it reflectively.  And your problems wouldn't end there.  All of this is almost certainly much more trouble than it's worth.

How about writing a subclass instead of a different version of the same class?

Comment: Actually I am working with hadoop.
There is a class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext in hadoop-1.2.1-core.jar and similar jar in hadoop 2.
Now I want create object based on which hadoop version I want to use.
Anyways thanks for a possible solution.

Comment: @user3655191, the *context* in which you use the code is not relevant to the answer.  If you mean that you're asking about code in some language other than Java, then it would behoove you to tag your question with the appropriate language tag instead of with [java].

Comment: using two versions of the same library in the same classloader will probably end up having subsequent issues caused by the same "first class found" issue. using mutiple classloaders may be the only practical way to solve it. or stick to one version.

Comment: Yes indeed, @SlipperySeal.  That's part of what I refer to when I say "And your problems wouldn't end there."  Even using a separate ClassLoader for each of the jars would still be likely to afford problems.  Depending on what the code needs to do, it might be possible to make this work, but as I said, it's almost certainly more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @JohnBollinger agreed.

Comment: if a one jar contains a class with single arg contructor and other jar contains the same class with 2 args constructor, then you can not compile above code fragment.

Comment: @hunter, you are correct, and this is consistent with my answer.  Did you mean to comment directly on the question?

Answer (score -1):

Changes the order of dependency in your pom. import the jar which you want upfront.

Comment: This does not make it possible to choose which one to use depending in the constructor,